# Change primary color dynamically in Material UI theme

Tags: reactjs, themes, material-ui

There is requirement, I want to give access to user can select their primary color from list like Blue, Orange Green. I have used the latest Material UI for front-end.

Now I am able to change light to dark theme but my requirement is change primary color also. please help me for same how to code for same.

Please check attached screen:

[image]

Comment: Please add some code at least of what you have already done.

Comment: I don't have any specific code for change primary color but yes I have two themes Light and Dark on-selection of radio button I am changing theme name of MUIThemeProvide<MuiThemeProvider theme={selectedTheme}>My App </MuiThemeProvider> and for light and dark theme I am using simple theme.js with color palettes

Comment: I want to change  palette: {
        type: "light",
        primary:  { 
            main: '#00ad9c',
        },
        secondary: { 
            main: '#00ad9c', 
         
        } },                                                                                                                                                       primary main palette value dynamically.

Comment: did you find a solutions? can you share it with us?

Answer (score 29):

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Root from './Root';

import lightTheme from 'your-light-theme-path';
import darkTheme from 'your-dark-them-path';

const theme1 = createMuiTheme(lightTheme);
const theme2 = createMuiTheme(darkTheme)

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isThemeLight: true;
  }
  onChange = () => {
    this.setState=({ isThemeLight: false })
  }
  render() {
     const { isThemeLight } = this.state;
     return (
       <MuiThemeProvider theme={isThemeLight ? theme1 : theme2}>
         <Root /> // your app here
         <button onClick={this.onChange}>Change Dark</button>
       </MuiThemeProvider>
     );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Where your `lightTheme` or `darkTheme` can be a file like this

```
export default {
  direction: 'ltr',
  palette: {
    type: 'light',
     primary: {
       main: '#37b44e',
     },
     secondary: {
       main: '#000',
     },
  },
};
```

You can see all the list of theme configurable in Material UI Docs [Theme Configuration](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/)

**Approach 2 (For Theme Change Runtime)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Root from './Root';

const theme1 = createMuiTheme(lightTheme);
const theme2 = createMuiTheme(darkTheme)

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    theme1: {
       palette: {
         type: 'light',
         primary: { main: '#37b44e' },
         secondary: { main: '#000' },
       },
    };
    theme2: {
       palette: {
         type: 'light',
         primary: { main: '#37b44e' },
         secondary: { main: '#000' },
       },
    };
    isThemeLight: true;
  }
  onChange = () => {
    this.setState=({ isThemeLight: false })
  }
  onChangeTheme1 = () => {
    this.setState(({theme1}) => ({
       theme1: { 
        ...theme1,
        primary: { main: 'red' },
       }
    }));
  }
  render() {
     const { theme1, theme2, isThemeLight } = this.state;
     return (
       <MuiThemeProvider 
         theme={isThemeLight ? createMuiTheme(theme1) : createMuiTheme(theme2)}
       >
         <Root /> // your app here
         <button onClick={this.onChange}>Change Dark</button>
         <button onClick={this.onChangeTheme1}>Change Palette Theme 1</button>
       </MuiThemeProvider>
     );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: My light and dark theme is working perfect.. But I want to change primary color  palette run-time on selection of color like Green or Orange.

Comment: changing mui theme in run time works great, but I noticed that every time the function `createMuiTheme` is called, a bunch of css styles files added at run time, so changing the theme for 10 times will create 10(or probably more) identical files!

Comment: @LouayAlosh Anecdotally, with `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2"` in my project, building in production mode i.e. `npm run build && serve -s build` results in the internal css styles like `<style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiIconButton">` being replaced properly, appending only occurs when running using the react webpack dev server https://i.imgur.com/y8NuHAV.mp4

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to compute the theme object whenever the `primaryColor` state changes. The state can be updated with `setPrimaryColor()` after the user chose an option in the UI:

```
const [primaryColor, setPrimaryColor] = React.useState(defaultColor);
const theme = React.useMemo(
  () =>
    createTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: {
          main: primaryColor,
        },
      },
    }),
  [primaryColor],
);
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
const defaultColor = '#f44336';
const [primaryColor, setPrimaryColor] = React.useState(defaultColor);
const theme = React.useMemo(
  () =>
    createTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: { main: primaryColor },
      },
    }),
  [primaryColor],
);

return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Box m={2}>
      <TextField
        select
        sx={{ width: 100 }}
        label="Primary color"
        defaultValue={defaultColor}
        onChange={(e) => setPrimaryColor(e.target.value)}
      >
        <MenuItem value="#f44336">Red</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="#2196f3">Blue</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="#4caf50">Green</MenuItem>
      </TextField>
      <Checkbox defaultChecked />
    </Box>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Clean and concise! this works perfect for my small use case.