# Toggle between TWO themes in MATERIALUI dynamically

Tags: reactjs, themes, overriding, material-ui

I would like to toggle between two themes in React using MaterialUI

I am using MUIthemeprovider from materialui/core. But somehow, I can't switch between the two themes.

```
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={currentTheme}>
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={currentTheme1}>
      <DarkModeProvider>
      <CssBaseline />
        <LocationProvider >
        <NavBar />
          <PageContent>
            <Routes/> 
          </PageContent>
        </LocationProvider>
      </DarkModeProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
```

I have tried using the themeprovider from https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/. But it is not using the materialui default theme format. So I can't access theme.palette.primary, theme.overrides & etc...

Right now, I have created a themeprovider and wrapped my navbar/pagecontent/routes in it. I am using useContext in most components to read the 'toggledstate' and then change the 'bg&text color' using classes/inline styles.

This is becoming more tedious and inefficient. Is there a smarter way to do this?

```
       const { isDarkMode, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);              

       <MenuItem style={isDarkMode ? {backgroundColor: '#1565c0'} :  
            {backgroundColor: '#343a40'}} 
            className={classes.menuItemDisplay} onClick= 
            {handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem style={isDarkMode ? {backgroundColor: '#1565c0'} :  
            {backgroundColor: '#343a40'}} 
        <Paper style={isDarkMode ? {backgroundColor: 
         '#1565c0',height:'100vh'} :  {backgroundColor: 
         '#343a40',height:'100vh'}}>
```

As you can see, if I have 100 components that i have to change colors. I have to do this 100 times. Hmmmm... I pretty there's a better way? Please advise!

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52379329) has what you are looking for (see Approach 2)

Comment: Yes. I was able to change the color. What if i want to change the component styles itself? I find it hard to do it without inline styles. Like changing the background color, icon color. I'm trying to do it using them overrides. (eg. Mui.AppBar, MuiList, MuiListitem.)   But it's not efficient.

Comment: not quite sure but maybe you can try conditional import like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50695901)