# Why the theme doesnt change to darkmode - using Material ui ThemeProvider? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: material-ui, themes, darkmode

on my `app.tsx` file

```
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Paper>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
          {/* <AnimatedWrapper children></AnimatedWrapper> */}
        </Paper>
      </ThemeProvider>
```

then I made a `useDarkMode.ts` function

```
export const useDarkMode = () => {
  const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const palletType = darkState ? 'dark' : 'light';
  const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: palletType,
    },
  });

  return { darkState, setDarkState, darkTheme };
};
```

and I am using `Switcher` from material ui on the `NavBar` component

```
export const NavBar = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { darkState, setDarkState } = useDarkMode();
  const classes = useStyles();

...

 <Typography className={classes.logoText}>
            <Switch checked={darkState} onChange={() => setDarkState(!darkState)} />
          </Typography>
```

Comment: it seems like your state variable is not updating..

Comment: I understand that I just dont know how to fix it I added also a useEffect but still is not updating the state....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52379329 this may help you to understand..